# Как реализовать построение графика из данных CSV файла?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, визуализация

У меня есть файл CSV со следующим содержимым:

```
1981,  10, 0.056, 272.73, 25.25, 37.63, 31.44,\
1982,  11, 0.069,  275.46, 26.81, 34.79, 30.80,\
1983,  12, 0.085,  278.05, 27.87, 35.91, 31.89,\
1984,  13, 0.096,  279.89, 26.45, 40.30, 33.37,\
1985,  14, 0.109,  281.55, 22.93, 45.47, 34.20,\
1986,  15, 0.120,  282.57, 16.15, 59.42, 37.78,
```

Нужно реализовать построение графика, исходя из этих данных. За ось X отвечают года, за Y- данные из последнего столбца.

Создаю следующий фрейм:

```
data = pd.read_csv('путь к файлу', skiprows=c,nrows=d).

data2 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
```

Параметры пропуска я получаю при запуске, т.е. возможны варианты вывода графика как с 1981 по 1985, так и с 1983-1985. Таким образом я рассчитывал реализовать пропуск ненужных данных при считывании.

Далее, делаю еще одну переменную, которая должна в себе содержать только последний столбец:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data2['G'])
```

И соответственно, теперь осталось использовать этот набор данных для построения графика.

Проблема в том, что в переменную `df` записываются `NaN`.

Как это грамотно (или же хоть как-то) реализовать, чтобы я сам это смог понять?
csv файл https://dropmefiles.com/4vUsn 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если взять ваш пример, то график получается линией, как раз то что мне и нужно, при использовании данных с другого файла, картина меняется, не подскажете, как изменить его вид? Пробовал стиль графика менять, закончилось тем, что график становился просто линией внизу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, usecols=[0,6], 
                 names=["year", "val"], index_col=0)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит DataFrame после чтения данных:

```
In [260]: df
Out[260]:
        val
year
1981  31.44
1982  30.80
1983  31.89
1984  33.37
1985  34.20
1986  37.78
```

PS если фрейм нужно отфильтровать по годам:

```
df = df.query("1981 <= year <= 1985")
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, при использовании другого csv файла, в котором данных больше, но они +- идентичны этим, график начинает строиться вообще в другом стиле, проблема в самих данных файла или же в самом построении ? Прикреплю фото и ссылку на файл. Что странно, я использую всего лишь больше данных

Comment: @Vladeezy, без картинки сложно сказать

Comment: я прикрепил и картинку и ссылку на файл, куда-то исчезли, сейчас редактирую

Comment: @Vladeezy, лучше открыть новый вопрос